# take a list of names from one file and replace the variable in another file

Tags: variables, powershell, replace, ldap

Here is my problem:

I have a list of Numbers: 183 rows in total (in csv file or txt file)

```
437735121495357

323099286491547

453369992736587

556548989085878
```

I need to take one row of 15 digits and replace the variable: %VariableUID in this file, continually to all rows of digits and variables have been replaced

```
dn: uid=%VariableUID, ou=People, o=aims.edu, o=cp

changetype: modify
delete: pdsRole
pdsRole: generic
-
add: pdsRole
pdsRole: student

dn: uid=%VariableUID, ou=People, o=aims.edu, o=cp

changetype: modify
delete: pdsRole
pdsRole: generic
-
add: pdsRole
pdsRole: student

dn: uid=%VariableUID, ou=People, o=aims.edu, o=cp
changetype: modify
delete: pdsRole
pdsRole: generic
```

each %VariableUID would be replaced by the next set of digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after more and more searching I ended up answer my own question with a powershell script. I wasn't able to modifiy an existing template..but I was able to use powershell script to format the txt file to replace my template:

```
#Location of Source File and Alias
$Source= gc "C:\Users\amoore19\Desktop\LDAP\ui-3rd-party.txt"
#takes each row in the Source File and replace the variable: $ouid in the following format
foreach ($ouid in $Source)
{
write-output "
dn: uid=$ouid, ou=People, o=aims.edu, o=cp
changetype: modify
delete: pdsRole
pdsRole: generic
-
add: pdsRole
pdsRole: student"  | Out-File -filepath "C:\Users\amoore19\Desktop\LDAP\ui-3rd-party-test1.txt" -append
#sets the output location filename and appends each invidiual output at the bottom of existing output (instead of replacing)
}
```

Results look like this:

```
dn: uid=437735121495324, ou=People, o=aims.edu, o=cp
changetype: modify
delete: pdsRole
pdsRole: generic
-
add: pdsRole
pdsRole: student

dn: uid=323099286491410, ou=People, o=aims.edu, o=cp
changetype: modify
delete: pdsRole
pdsRole: generic
-
add: pdsRole
pdsRole: student
```